# Not full size border-bottom for table

Tags: html, css, border

I make **RWD** table, but I need to make `border-bottom` shorter than full size. I tried `:before` and `:after`, but position `absolute` does not work well with RWD table.

What should I use to create the horizontal rule? `<hr>` or anything else?

Comment: please you can post your code or fiddle?

Comment: Please provide fiddle or demo first so we can see the issue and can try to help.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdypEJ

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `width` property of `hr` to adjust. Change your CSS

```
.logo {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}
```

to

```
.logo hr {
  width: 90%;
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}
```

and add `<hr>` below your `<h1>xxxsadw.pl</h1>`. Updated [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwYEZN)

Comment: Yeah, I done it this way earlier, but it does not work good... Now I know that it works! Thanks.